# Don't save fragment state in ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I am using `ViewPager2` with `FragmentStateAdapter` and if I have three fragments the default behavior is to save fragment state, actually I have one fragment but create instances and pass different types to it, so if I have Fragment A, A1 and A2 and I scroll from a1 to a then back to a the adapter doesn't recreate A but use an old instance of A and that's what is happening to me

But instead, I don't want that behaviour I want the adapter to create a new instance of fragment A instead of using the last instance and then if I scroll to B create a new instance of B and don't use the last instance.

```
public class JobsViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {


private List<Integer> fragmentsType = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
    add(JobsType.Booked.numValue);
    add(JobsType.INVITED.numValue);
    add(JobsType.PAST.numValue);
}};

public JobsViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    return JobsInnerFragment.newInstance(fragmentsType.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fragmentsType.size();
}


public enum JobsType {
    Booked(0), TODAY(1), INVITED(2), UPCOMING(3), PAST(4);

    private int numValue;

    JobsType(int value) {
        this.numValue = value;
    }

    public int getNumValue() {
        return numValue;
    }
}
```

}

```
 public static JobsInnerFragment newInstance(int jobsType){
    JobsInnerFragment jobFragment = new JobsInnerFragment();
    Bundle todayJobsBundle = new Bundle();
    todayJobsBundle.putInt(Constants.JOBS_TYPE, jobsType);
    jobFragment.setArguments(todayJobsBundle);
    return jobFragment;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `offscreenPageLimit` to `ViewPager` as 1

```
viewPager2.offscreenPageLimit=1
```

From documentation

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the currently visible page(s). Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: I have already tried that  but nothing have been changed